# Rails survey submission form is not rendering questions and answers as input fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

#### Edited

I'm working on an app that is intended to be a rough clone of survey monkey.

Survey's act as the 'template' and submissions are responses to that survey template.

I have a show page that leads to a form for a new submission. I have the correct survey template and the associated models/attributes I require (confirmed in pry), however I can't get any of the associated questions and answers to render as form input fields.

## controllers/surveys_controller.rb

```
  before_action :set_survey, except: [:index, :new, :create, :home, :mysurveys]

  def show
    @survey.submissions.build
  end

  private

  def survey_params
    params[:survey].permit(:user_id, :title, questions_attributes: [:id, :prompt, :_destroy, answers_attributes: [:id, :content, :_destroy]])
  end

  def set_survey
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  end
```

## views/surveys/show.html.erb

```
<h1>This is the show page for surveys.</h1>

<h3><%= @survey.title %></h3>

<% if current_user == @survey.user_id %>
  <%= render "mysurvey" %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'survey_form' %>
<% end %>
```

## views/surveys/_survey_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <% @survey.questions.each do |q| %>
    <%= q.prompt %>
      <%= f.text_field %>

    <% q.answers.each do |a| %>
      <%= a.content %>
      <%= f.text_field %>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried `f.text_field :q`, `:questions`, `:prompt` `q.prompt`. Rails just returns `undefined method`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `show.html.erb`

```
<h1>This is the show page for surveys.</h1>

<h3><%= @survey.title %></h3>

<% if current_user == @survey.user_id %>
  <% render "mysurvey" %>
<% else %>
  <% render 'survey_form' %>
<% end %>
```

Which should be like

```
<h1>This is the show page for surveys.</h1>

<h3><%= @survey.title %></h3>

<% if current_user == @survey.user_id %>
  <%= render "mysurvey" %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'survey_form' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Well that was an easy fix. The issue now is that the input fields require a model attribute to associate the field input value with the attribute, however rails doesn't seem to accept anything I've tried passing in.

Comment: To work `survey_form` partial form ... you have to pass `@survey` variable like `<%= render partial: 'survey_form' :locals => { survey: @survey} %>`. If `mysurvey` partial form needs to pass variable you should pass variable like this.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect. The issue is this input field. This `<%= f.text_field %>` requires an argument that I had thought would be the `:prompt` attribute of `q` but nothing seems to work thus far.